# Is it possible to configure Vite so source code is bundled in development, instead of being loaded as individual modules over the network?

Tags: vite

By default, Vite will load every module imported into an application's entrypoints over the network. This is a performance optimization for small apps, but in larger applications with thousands of files this produces extreme lag on the initial page load as these thousands of files are requested over HTTP.

In a test environment like Cypress, where each tests produces a new page refresh, the entire source tree is loaded over the network for each test. This makes writing tests in development nearly impossible to manage in large applications.

How can we force Vite to prebundle the source code of an application, similar to how you might expect with Webpack?

Please note: I am not referring to dependency pre-bundling which bundles dependencies located in node_modules or linked monorepo modules. I am specifically wanting to bundle the application source code (for example your `src` folder).

Comment: Hey! Did you find an answer yet? I ran into the exact sasme problem but can only get chunking/bundling to work how I want for production builds, not during dev